# When i refresh page its not logged in, its redirect to login page

Tags: reactjs

```
  let userDetails = this.props.userDetails 
    let authenticate = userDetails !== undefined && userDetails !== '' && userDetails !== null && userDetails.userID !== '' ? true : false
    console.log(authenticate)
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>         
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/login' component={Loginpage}/>
            {authenticate &&
            <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
            }
            {authenticate &&
            <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
            }
            {authenticate &&
            <Route path='/blog' component={Blog} />
            }
            {authenticate &&
            <Route path='/contactus' component={Contactus} />
            }
            {authenticate &&
            <Route path='/chart' component={Charts} />
            }
            {authenticate &&
            <Route path='/myReads' component={MyReads} />
            }
            {authenticate &&
            <Route path='/myProfile' component={Profile} />
            }
           

              <Route exact path='*' component={Loginpg}/>  
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
```

Comment: Raj, when you refresh a web app, all the props values are lost. that is why your app is taking you to login page.Please try to save the user details where it is not lost on refresh like local storage or session storage or try to authenticate using token.

Answer (score 0):

of course on referesh the page will reset the state. so to solve this you need to save `authenticate` value in `locale storage` or `cookies` and get it when the application run and this not the best way to make protected route, it's better to create a `HOC` component which get if user is `autheticated` and then render the component.

here a full example for protected routes with local storage : [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-leakey-lree8?file=/src/App.js)